# How would I obfuscate a password on the client and deobfuscate at the server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

**I understand that this is not a good practice.**

I use fiddler, and I usually see the password in plain text even in https. I would like to have the client quickly obfuscate the password before sending it out. When the server receives the request, it should be able to deobfuscate it.

**Normally what I see in fiddler post to server**

```
{
    "secure_username": "mmatiasn",
    "secure_password": "chickennuggetboy" //Plain text password I hate to see...
}
```

**What I would like to see being posted to server**

```
{
    "secure_username": "mmatiasn",
    "secure_password": "d162314" //Obfuscate password that the server can deobfuscate.
}
```

I'm working on a small project to learn more about dotnet and it's currently only accessible over a small intranet network I own. I don't want to set up https as well.

Comment: The normally handler way is use `MD5` encode password.

Comment: I'm hosting it in my desktop and then use other computers in the network to connect to my computer. Browsers will freak out about the self-signed certificate. I'm looking to add a little bit of privacy to the password since I'm constantly looking at the HTTP request. I'm in no way even thinking about implementing it in real life just experimenting with different ways that data is protected.

Comment: @JohanShen "MD5" and "password" should not be used together in any sentence other than "do not hash passwords using MD5".

Comment: So far as the server is concerned, the password is now `d162314r983r3` and anyone snooping your traffic can just send that now - you've not gained anything by doing some work on the client (unless you also move to a more complex scheme which involves some form of server challenge)

Comment: BasicAuthentication transmits the username and password as a base64 encoded string.  Would this meet your requirement for simple obfuscation?  It goes without saying that this is not encryption.

Comment: @Joe I think obfuscation is what I'm actually trying to do. I don't care that someone can use it to login. Just that a person starting at my screen while I'm developing can't right away tell what my password is.

Comment: @Matt You can see the https traffic because you are essentially setting up a MITM, the solution is to pin the server certificate, that is not to allow the client to accept a certificate and thus communications from other than the server it expects to connect to. Yes security adds pain to an implementation, the tradeoff is the security of the users on a continuing basis vs the developer doing his job by providing correct security once.

Comment: Would a professional, knowing a method is "not a good practice", go forward with it anyway?

Comment: Your best bet is to set up an environment where this doesn't matter. If you can't rule out people looking over your shoulder, use test accounts with deliberately weak passwords in a test environment. If they muck things up, they only bother you a bit. Certainly do not reuse any users/passwords you use on live. Obfuscation isn't the answer to preventing accidents; not giving people peeks at things they're not supposed to see in the first place is. If you tried this on me, you can bet I'd memorize your `secure_password`, dig up the obfuscation code, then teach you an object lesson in security.

Answer (score 4):

You don't, just use `https` which is the standard (*for a reason*).

1. There is no need to do this, if there was then that would be the standard practice.
2. To hash the password you need the salt which should not leave the server (the hash shouldn't either but you don't need it to create a new hash).

Use `https` and send the password in the message body of the request (use POST or maybe PUT). Yes, you can see the content if you are the client or with fiddler in between if its your PC, that is by design. If you are outside of the client using a sniffer or something to intercept traffic then you cannot see the content as it is encrypted.

> ... only accessible over a small intranet network I own. I don't want to set up https as well.

Why? If its an intranet then use a self signed certificate (free) which is relatively simple to setup and takes almost no time and **much** less time (*not to mention secure*) than it would take to develop anything like what you are suggesting.

Comment: I'm hosting it in my desktop and then use other computers in the network to connect to my computer. Browsers will freak out about the self-signed certificate. I'm looking to add a little bit of privacy to the password since I'm constantly looking at the HTTP request. I'm in no way even thinking about implementing it in real life just experimenting with different ways that data is protected.

Comment: @Matt - `Browsers will freak out about the self-signed certificate` <= no, they display a message that the certificate is not from a trusted source and cant be validated. Its a matter of training the users that want to use your little test site on your intranet how to accept the certificate (probably only 1x per browser).

Comment: @Igor in a properly configured environment, the users don't have permissions to do that.

Comment: @CodeCaster - my response to that would be in a properly configured environment the users browser would not "freak out" (taken from OP) as the IT staff could push out a company (or self) signed certificate (or recognition thereof) with a policy.

Comment: @Igor of course, but either obtaining a self-signed certificate from the IT staff that's trusted company-wide or installing a self-signed certificate that the OP delivers to IT is not trivial in most organizations I'm familiar with. Then there's still firewalls. Either way, running an HTTPS service internally is generally not trivial. I'm not saying HTTPS is _not_ a solution, because it is _the_ solution, it will probably just be hard to set up properly.

Comment: @CodeCaster fair enough, in those situations it probably involves some paperwork and IT requests. The OP does mention that they own that intranet and the web app is only accessible on there so based on that alone it probably should be something relatively easy to do. Also they mention `"I dont want to setup https..." so that also leaves met to believe that he would be deploying it and not a IT crew. Though at this point we are merely speculating....

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: @zaph - this answer makes no guess at to what password method is used or suggestion of which one to use. The only thing that might resemble that is the mention that most password algorithms do use a unique salt in the process and that the salt should not leave the server in a web based environment.

Comment: Guys, I revised the question as it was misleading as to what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Igor You are providing information on hashing the password and needing salt, that is not sufficient for passwords.

Comment: @zaph - I am not sure what you are getting at. I am advocating that the OP **not** try to do any type of hashing of the password on the client. Also I am not providing any information about hashing at all.

Comment: @Igor My comment is not directed toward you personally. It is pointing out that using a hash, even salted, it not a secure method to handle passwords.

Comment: @zaph - ok, well in that case I am in agreement with you.